# Calculating each average of given list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, average

Assume that I have an input as `[(1,2,3),(4.5,-2,7.4)]`.
I need an output like `(2.0,3.3)`.
I cannot use any `import`s.
I know an average is like:

```
list = int(input())
ave = sum(list)/len(list)
print(list)
```

but I don't know how to calculate each tuple's average.
Ok now I know the answer my codes is as follows:

`list = list(x)`

`print([sum(i) / len(i) for i in list])`

x is just the value I named to read the input list of tuples as string and I have to, I cannot change it, but when I put `[(15.5, 8, 16.46), (7, 56, 4.21884, -1.4, 8.3), ((4.5,-2,7.4)]` as input, I get `[13.32, 14.823767999999998, 3.3000000000000003]`.
I want to get `(13.32 , 14.82, 3.33)` as output and I am not allowed to use `round()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a list comprehension:

```
lst = [(1, 2, 3), (4.5, -2, 7.4)]
print([sum(i) / len(i) for i in lst])
```

Output:

```
[2.0, 3.3]
```

Comment: Can you look at it again?